# program based on arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

my program is a simple shopping list , it should ask the user to enter what he wants , then , if the item is in the shopping list , it will print a special message, and it will store it in an array , and vice versa.
finally , my program should print all the items that the user has entered and found it in my shopping list, and also should print the items that he has not found it ...

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char x;
string supplies[4] = {"apple", "banana" , "egg", "love"};
string shopping_cart[4];
string wanted_goods[4];
string good;

bool found;
int gd_counter=0;
int wd_counter=0;

cout << "welcome to my shopping list, tap A to cont. and B to quit!" << endl;
cin >> x;

while(x == 'A' || x == 'B'){
  if(x == 'B'){
    break;
  }
  else{
    cout << "Type the name of the item!" << endl;
    cin >> good;
    for(int y=0; y<4; y++ ){
      if( good == supplies[y]){
      found = true;  // edited 
        // continue;
      }
      if(found == true){
        shopping_cart[wd_counter++] = good; // edited 
        cout << "we have that item"; // edited 
      }
      else{
        wanted_goods[wd_counter++] = good; // edited 
        cout << "we do not have that item!"; // edited 
      }

    }
  cout << "do you want to complete!?" << endl;
  cin >> x;
  }
}

for(int z=0; z<gd_counter; z++){
  cout << shopping_cart[z] << endl; // print out what the user has found in my shopping list
}

for(int c=0; c<wd_counter; c++){
  cout << wanted_goods[c] << endl; // print out the items that the user has not found it
}
}
```

thanks for helping me !

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to fix the program , i tried so many times ...

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you should always try to describe what exactly isn't working and what you tried in order to fix it. Most times writing it down already helps you to solve your own mistakes. Nevertheless here are some tips:

There are at least 3 mistakes in your code.

The first one is that `sizeof(supplies)` returns the size of supplies in the matter of bytes not in the number of elements. So as suggested by *Hi I'm Frogatto* you should use either `std::size(supplies)` or `sizeof(supplies) / sizeof(supplies[0])` (Bytes for all elements over size of one element equals the number of elements).

Note that using `std::size` requires *c++17* and `#include <iterator>` according to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size). I would highly recommend to use the `c++11` template [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which offers `array.size()`. It's widely supported and in basically all means better to use than the native array when writting modern *c++* code.

The second problem is that you iterate over the list of items available and everytime you miss *one* you *directly* add it to the list of *not found* things. E.g. if you enter apple then it doesn't match banana, egg and love  and will be added to the list of things that we're not found three times. You should first iterate over the list to find if the item was in the list saving the result in a boolean and then add it to the corrosponding list. If you do not want to code it yourself you might want to take a look at [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) which works nicely with `std::array<>`.

```
cout << "Type the name of the item!" << endl;
cin >> good;
bool found = false;
for(int y=0; y < supplies.size(); y++) {
  if(good == supplies[y])
    found = true;
}
if (found) {
    shopping_cart[gd_counter++] = good;
    cout << "we have that item!" << endl;
} else {
    wanted_goods[wd_counter++] = good;
    cout << "we do not have that item!" << endl;
}
```

The third problem is that you allow the user the enter an unlimited number of items while your buffers only have space for four items. As soon as someone enters more than 4 found or unfound items your indices run out of the scope of the arrays and trigger a segfault (or a security issue with possible code injection).

```
while (x == 'A' || x == 'B'){
  if(x == 'B'){
    break;
  }
  else {
    // handle user input here
    if (gd_counter < shopping_cart.size()
       && wd_counter < wanted_goods.size()) {
        cout << "do you want to complete!?" << endl;
        cin >> x;
    } else {
        cout << "you can't add more items!" << endl;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

All in all your code works for me like this (you can try this [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gsGLHR9D8h3EkzhE)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char x;
    std::array<string, 4> supplies{"apple", "banana" , "egg", "love"};
    std::array<string, 4> shopping_cart;
    std::array<string, 4> wanted_goods;
    string good;

    int gd_counter=0;
    int wd_counter=0;

    cout << "welcome to my shopping list, tap A to cont. and B to quit!" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    while (x == 'A' || x == 'B'){
      if(x == 'B'){
        break;
      }
      else {
        cout << "Type the name of the item!" << endl;
        cin >> good;
        if (std::find(supplies.begin(), supplies.end(), good) != supplies.end()) {
            shopping_cart[gd_counter++] = good;
            cout << "we have that item!" << endl;
        } else {
            wanted_goods[wd_counter++] = good;
            cout << "we do not have that item!" << endl;
        }

        if (gd_counter < shopping_cart.size()
           && wd_counter < wanted_goods.size()) {
            cout << "do you want to complete!?" << endl;
            cin >> x;
        } else {
            cout << "you can't add more items!" << endl;
            break;
        }
      }
    }

    cout << "shopping card:" << endl;
    for(int z=0; z<gd_counter; z++){
      cout << shopping_cart[z] << endl; // print out what the user has found in my shopping list
    }

    cout << "wanted goods:" << endl;
    for(int c=0; c<wd_counter; c++){
        cout << wanted_goods[c] << endl; // print out the items that the user has not found it
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want more tips on how to improve your coding you should probably ask on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But please make sure your code works before posting there.

Answer (score 0):

The following line doesn't work as you expect.

```
for(int y = 0; y < sizeof(supplies); y++ ){
```

Note that `sizeof(supplies)` doesn't return the length of the array. You should use [`std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) instead.

```
for(int y = 0; y < std::size(supplies); y++ ){
```

Comment: Or `sizeof supplies / sizeof supplies[0]`

Comment: still not working , i will update my code with the new one

Answer (score 0):

Or `_countof(supplies)`, it is included in `stdlib.h` on windows.

(I cannot make a comment, so I posted a new one.)

Comment: it 50% works , but the other part of the program does not work perfectrly , when i print what the user has ordered and what are the things that he did not find it , it prints duplicated items ..